# Why would I get ExecutionEngineException in OpenRead on X509CertificateStore?

Tags: c#, certificate

I'm using the WebServicesClientProtocol class with security tokens and using the following code to find the security token to use:

```
private static X509SecurityToken GetSecurityCertificate(string subject)
{
    X509CertificateStore localStore = X509CertificateStore.LocalMachineStore(X509CertificateStore.MyStore);
    X509SecurityToken securityToken = null;
    if (localStore.OpenRead())
    {
       X509CertificateCollection certificateCollection = localStore.FindCertificateBySubjectString(subject);
        if (certificateCollection.Count == 0) throw new Exception("Skilríki finnst ekki í skilríkjageymslu");
        securityToken = new X509SecurityToken((X509Certificate)certificateCollection[0]);
    }
    localStore.Close();
    return securityToken;
}
```

Every now and then (but not always and I haven't been able to figure out when exactly) I get the following exception:

[alt text http://www1.ruedenet.is/files/exception.png](http://www1.ruedenet.is/files/exception.png)

Comment: I have the same problem actually. Have you found a solution to this, if so it'd be excellent if you could post your answer here

Comment: Sorry - still no solution. Yes, I will post the solution if I find one. Please do the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today and I believe I've figured out what has been causing it. The static method requires synchronization.

If you hover over your localStore variable at the time of the exception and inspect the Certificates property you'll most likely see something to the effect of "InvalidOperationException - To access the certificates you must use Open() or OpenRead()... blah blah blah".

What is happening is some thread is closing the store before another thread is finished accessing it.

I solved the issue by first creating a static class member for locking the store:

```
private static object m_storeLock = new object();
```

When you access the store you'll have to do something like the following:

```
public static X509Certificate FindCertificate(string certName) {
    X509CertificateStore store = null;            
    X509Certificate cert = null;

    lock (m_storeLock) {
        try {                    
            store = X509CertificateStore.LocalMachineStore(X509CertificateStore.MyStore);
            store.OpenRead();

            X509CertificateCollection col =
            (X509CertificateCollection)store.FindCertificateBySubjectString(certName);

            if (col.Count > 0) {      
                cert = col[0];
            }
        }
        catch {
        }
        finally {
            if (store != null) {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
    }                           

    if (cert == null) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Certificate not found!");
    }

    return cert;
}
```

To be extra safe, you should probably lock the local variable "cert", but this is not production code guys... :D~